# How to handle multiple file as multipart request in AWS Lambda using API Gateway Proxy?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I am searching for a workaround by which, I can handle multiple files as multipart form data request with AWS Lambda and API Gateway as proxy.

To handle single file I am following [this](https://github.com/CorkHounds/multipart-fileupload-java-lambda/blob/master/src/main/java/fileupload/FileUploadFunctionHandler.java),

```
public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event, Context context)
{

    try
    {

        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(event.getBody().getBytes());

        // Get the content-type header and extract the boundary
        Map<String, String> headers = event.getHeaders();

        String contentType = null;

        if (headers != null && !headers.isEmpty())
        {
            contentType =
                    headers.get("content-type") != null ? headers.get("content-type") : headers.get("Content-Type");
        }

        String[] boundaryArray = contentType.split("=");

        // Transform the boundary to a byte array
        byte[] boundary = boundaryArray[1].getBytes();

        ByteArrayInputStream content = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        // Create a MultipartStream to process the form-data
        MultipartStream multipartStream = new MultipartStream(content, boundary, bytes.length, null);

        // Create a ByteArrayOutputStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Find first boundary in the MultipartStream
        boolean nextPart = multipartStream.skipPreamble();

        // Loop through each segment
        while (nextPart)
        {
            String header = multipartStream.readHeaders();

            context.getLogger().log("Headers:");

            context.getLogger().log(header);

            // Write out the file to our ByteArrayOutputStream
            multipartStream.readBodyData(out);

            // Get the next part, if any
            nextPart = multipartStream.readBoundary();
        }

            //Prepare an InputStream from the ByteArrayOutputStream
            InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

    }
```

is it possible to handle multiple files?

Comment: Hey
any luck for multiple files?

Comment: New solution available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65279215/3866010